# How do I produce the average result using map reduce programming?

Tags: database, mongodb, mapreduce, nosql

I'm using Mongodb to try and figure out the average milage in my motor cars collection using the map reduce method. I know how to figure out the minimum value (as displayed below), however I don't know how this works for average. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

```
var map = function(){
    emit(this.Classification, this.Milage); };

var reduce = function(key, values){
        var minvalue = values[0];
        values.forEach(function(value){
        if(minvalue>value){
            minvalue = value;
        }
    })
return minvalue};

db.ads.mapReduce(map,reduce, {
    query: {Classification: "Motor Cars"},
    out: {inline: 1}
});
```

Comment: don't know mongo but just add all the values together and divide by len(values) or have a missed something?

Comment: The query is not supposed to know the values before it is ran. It is supposed to take the data from the table and find the average.

Comment: +var reduce = function(key, values){
        var totalValue = 0
        values.forEach(function(value){
            totalValue += value
    })
return totalValue/len(values)};

Comment: or something like that

Comment: Hia did that work for you (just curious)

Answer (score 0):

moved this from comments to answer

I don't know mongo but just add all the values together and divide by len(values) or have a missed something -- some pseudo code:

```
var reduce = function(key, values){ var totalValue = 0 values.forEach(function(value){ totalValue += value }) return totalValue/len(values)};
```